# Vim folding configuration for programming

Tags: javascript, perl, vim, folding

I am having trouble with vim folding.
I work with perl, javascript, c/c++, html using vim. Can anyone suggest a good folding configuration?
I ideally the function will be folded and if possible I would like to be able to fold for loops

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
set foldmethod=indent
```

for all the languages I work with.

Use `za` to toggle folding, `zM` to fold everything, `zR` to unfold everything, `zm` to fold more, `zr` to fold less.

Comment: +1. Interesting. 1) I thought that the `set foldenable` is mandatory for folds to work. It is not? 2) Is there an option to start vim and not to have everything folded? 3) For loops seem to behave strange, am I missing something? 4)I see that `zc` works as well besides the ones you mention

Comment: 1) No, read `:help foldenable` carefully. 2) `:help foldlevelsart`. 3) hard to say without more information. 4) I prefer `za` to `zc`+`zo` but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Like romainl, I think that when it comes to folding, simple is better. Maintaining folding settings for different filetypes is a pain. I used to be a `foldmethod=indent` guy; nowadays I use `foldmethod=marker` because it gives me unlimited flexibility.

Comment: But how exactly do you use it? What is your vim setting also?

Comment: I use `set foldmethod=marker` for every filetype. I manually set fold markers in comment lines on regions I want folded away. Use can use `UltiSnips` snippets to make that easier.